# Spring security: Autowired userDetailsService

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I trying to implement custom authorization based on spring security. 
Here is the config.xml:

```
<global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled" />
    <http use-expressions="true">
        <form-login login-page="/wellcome/" login-processing-url="/login" default-target-url="/" 
            username-parameter="email" password-parameter="password" />
        <remember-me key="skyhandling" token-validity-seconds="-1" />
        <logout invalidate-session="true" logout-success-url="/" logout-url="/logout"/>
        <intercept-url pattern="/administration/**" access="authenticated"/>
        <intercept-url pattern="/wellcome/" access="permitAll"/>
        <intercept-url pattern="/login" access="permitAll"/>
        <intercept-url pattern="/css/**" access="permitAll"/>
        <intercept-url pattern="/images/**" access="permitAll"/>
        <intercept-url pattern="/javascript/**" access="permitAll"/>
    </http>
    <beans:bean id="authenticationProvider"
        class="org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider">
        <beans:property name="userDetailsService" ref="userDetailsService"/>
    </beans:bean>
    <beans:bean id="authenticationManager"
        class="org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager">
        <beans:property name="providers">
            <beans:list>
                <beans:ref local="authenticationProvider" />
            </beans:list>
        </beans:property>
    </beans:bean>
    <beans:bean class="com.test.service.UserDetailsExtendedService" id="userDetailsService" />
    <beans:bean class="org.springframework.security.authentication.encoding.ShaPasswordEncoder" 
        id="passwordEncoder" />
    <authentication-manager>
        <authentication-provider user-service-ref="userDetailsService">
            <password-encoder ref="passwordEncoder" />
        </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>
```

User details service:

```
@Service("userDetailsService")
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public class UserDetailsExtendedService implements UserDetailsService {
    @Autowired
    private UsersDAO dao;

    /**
     * 
     * @param user
     * @return
     */
    private User prepare(com.test.User user) {
        boolean enabled = user.getState().equals(UserState.Active);

        Collection<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>();
        for (UserRole r: user.getRoles()) {
          authorities.add(new GrantedAuthorityImpl(r.getName()));
        }

        return new UserDetailsExtended(user.getEmail(), user.getPassword(), user.getNickname(), enabled,
            enabled, enabled, enabled, authorities);
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param email
     * @return
     */
    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public User loadUserByUsername(final String email) 
            throws UsernameNotFoundException, DataAccessException {
        com.test.User user = dao.getByEmail(email);
        if (user == null)
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException(email);

        return prepare(user);
    }
}
```

Everything works fine. But when I add

```
@Autowired 
private UserDetailsExtendedService useDetailsService;
```

into Controller class the applicaton starts to fail with:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean of type [com.test.service.UserDetailsExtendedService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
```

What I missed? Thank you

UPD#1:

```
 <context:annotation-config />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.test.service" />
    <bean id="usersDao" class="com.test.dao.UsersDAO" />
    <bean id="eventsLogDao" class="com.test.dao.EventsLogDAO" />
    <bean id="employeesDao" class="com.test.dao.EmployeesDAO" />
    <bean id="dictionariesDao" class="com.test.dao.DictionariesDAO" />
```

Comment: In what file did you configure autoscanning?

Comment: in config. please see the UPD#1

Comment: It's just a sample.. Other services work fine with Autowired, userDetailsService the only one that fails.. but works fine in spring security

Comment: how is your config.xml picked up, what is the web.xml configuration for it?

Comment: I have three spring config files: security, data (for data binding) and service (for service initializtion). in web.config I add them by setting contextConfigLocation parameter

Answer (score 0):

In your configuration you have a `com.ejl.skyhandling.service.UserDetailsExtendedService` but 
in your bean you are trying to access `com.test.service.UserDetailsExtendedService` which is obviously another type.

Please check your imports.

Comment: I fixed it, this is for example

Answer (score 0):

Since you're qualifying @Service with value "userDetailsService" make sure the @Autowired is

```
@Autowired
private UserDetailsExtendedService userDetailsService;
```

You currently are missing the r in the variable name -> useDetailsService

Comment: It does not work. still getting    ` Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: com.hello.services.auth.UserManagementService com.hello.configuration.security.SecurityConfig.userDetailsService; nested exception is *.*.*.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.hello.services.auth.UserManagementService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. `